# Is it possible to overcome 250 item limit in Python/Code By Zapier step?

Tags: python, zapier

I am using Code By Zapier step for fetching records from a remote database. This is essentially a remote SELECT query and I parse the response, process the records and then pack them nicely in the OUTPUT dictionary so that my next app can read it one record at a time, and take it from there.

Now, my queries are scheduled to run monthly, and I am getting between 275-400 records per month via these queries, which correlates to my OUTPUT dictionary size.

I discovered to my rude surprise that Zapier only allows 250 items from the OUTPUT dictionary. I was aware of the memory limits of the code step but I had naively imagined that OUTPUT size will also be subject to this memory limit. Turns out this is a hard limit.

My question #1: will upgrade to a bigger plan give me a larger item size limit?

Question #2: Are there any suggestions on how to circumvent this limitation? I know that Zapier is currently not supporting loop within a zap, but is there any way I can "code" around this?

I know perhaps running the same zap on two consecutive days, etc. may be a possibility, but that has some other drawbacks in this situation.

Also, an additional question pertaining to the limits: -- the 10sec, 256MB running memory limit: is this per zap, or is this per code step? Meaning, if I split my zap code into 2 parts, then will I get 10 sec each for either steps?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Great questions!

> will upgrade to a bigger plan give me a larger item size limit?

No. Free users can return 25 items, paid users can return 250 items. This isn't a commonly used feature, so it's not something Zapier prices around. I'm not sure why that limit exists, but it's a hard limit.

> the 10sec, 256MB running memory limit: is this per zap, or is this per code step?

It's per code step. But, be careful with your looping logic- if you put two code steps that both return arrays in sequence, then you'll have a lot of duplication. For example if each of code steps A and B are in sequence and return 10 items, then code step b will run 10 times and return 100 items (which is probably not what you want).

You seem to want the functionality of a trigger (return a list of objects, run the rest of the zap on each), so I'd set up your code as a trigger! There's not an item limit for triggers (though there is the aforementioned data size limit, but you should be fine).

The only tricky part is getting your Zap to run when you want it. Code triggers run during your polling window (15 minutes for free users, faster for paid). So, you'll need a `if` statement at the top of the code to return `[]` unless it's your specified day/time to run. Less elegant than a schedule trigger, but

One final thing to note - since your code is now part of a trigger, returned data will be subject to [deduplication](https://zapier.com/help/create/basics/data-deduplication-in-zaps) that it wasn't subject to before. Make sure that items returned either have a unique id (if you want every item to trigger every time) or repeat ids (if you're only interested in items you've never seen before). Unique ids can probably be synthesized by combining the actual ID with the date it's running.

Answer (score -1):

Zapier code step is based on serverless architecture and has upper bounds for execution time and memory. It is not supposed to run long-running integration or moving large data.

[image: I also hit same limitations for my usecase and started a side project to solve these problems. Hit me up on the: getstartx.tech [AT] gmail.com if you wish to discuss more.]

Comment: Thank you for the information.For a more expensive plan, Zapier will allow you to consume more memory (by code) and allow more execution time (up to 10 sec). Therefore, wondering if this memory size limit is also elastic and can be incremented per plan.